# Xamarin.Form iOS custom height ProgressBar issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

**UPDATED:**

So, I'm unable to create IOS custom height ProgressBar.
I use the latest version of Xamarin.Forms.

.cs file:

```
public class SplashScreenProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TintColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<CustomProgressBar, Color>( p => p.TintColor, Color.Green);

    public Color TintColor
    {
        get { return (Color) GetValue(TintColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TintColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty HeightExtendedProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("HeightExtended", typeof(double), typeof(SplashScreenProgressBar), 10.0);

    public double HeightExtended
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(HeightExtendedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeightExtendedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BackgroundColorExtendedProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("BackgroundColorExtended", typeof(Color), typeof(SplashScreenProgressBar),
            Color.White);

    public Color BackgroundColorExtended
    {
        get { return (Color) GetValue(BackgroundColorExtendedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundColorExtendedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Here is iOS renderer:

```
public class SplashScreenProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var element = (SplashScreenProgressBar)Element;
        this.Control.ProgressTintColor = element.TintColor.ToUIColor();
        this.Control.TrackTintColor = element.BackgroundColorExtended.ToUIColor();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var element = (SplashScreenProgressBar)Element;
        var X = 1.0f;
        var Y = (System.nfloat)element.HeightExtended;

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);

        this.Control.Transform = transform;
        this.Control.ClipsToBounds = true;
        this.Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        this.Control.CornerRadius = 5;
    }
}
```

xaml file:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  BackgroundColor="White" >
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="50" BackgroundColor="White" >
    <views:SplashScreenProgressBar  x:Name="Progress" 
                                   TintColor="#5FA5F9" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                   BackgroundColorExtended="#FFF"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

But this way doesn't work. 
I googled and tried almost all samples which I've found, but nothing happened.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

As you see on the screenshot corner radius is applied to ProgressBar, but height(scale) isn't applied.

[image: Screenshot1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In PCL

`StackLayout` is overlapped with status bar.

Add Margin on it.

```
<StackLayout Margin="50" xxxxx
```

#### In Renderer

`ClipsToBounds` ,`Layer.MasksToBounds` ,`Layer.CornerRadius` should be set on the `Control` not the `Renderer`

```
this.Control.Transform = transform;
this.Control.ClipsToBounds = true;
this.Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
this.Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't help. Could u share your code?

Comment: @Atlantis My code already shows below, Which part did you not get?

Comment: I've got it. I made changes and it unsuccessfully. Nothing changed.

Comment: What is the result?  Is there any change on the image's looks?

Comment: Yup. Small changes with corners.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167701/discussion-between-atlantis-and-cole-xia-msft).

Answer (score 0):

When use the custom renderer in ios, it always occupy the whole area of parent element. So, u need to update the progress bar frame once again in layoutsubview.
bool is rendered;

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
if(!rendered)
{
       Frame = new CGRect(x,y,width,height);
       setNeedsdisplay
}
rendered=true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I spent a lot of hours to researching  and investigation. 
And seems there xamarin.forms iOS bug for progress bar rounded corners.

Comment: Hi. Sample work, height is expanded, but corners isn't rounded.